# Startup script not working in Debian Squeeze

Tags: linux, debian, boot

In Debian Sqeeze, I created a script called `/etc/init.d/capslock` that contains this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Remapping Caps Lock key to Escape"
setkeycodes 0x3a 1
echo " ...done"
```

I made it executable, and linked it to /etc/rc2.d/S95capslock. When I run it from the command line, it works. But it doesn't fire on a reboot for some reason. Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a useful snippet, but when I try it, I get the error "KDSETKEYCODE: Invalid argument".

Anyway, for Squeeze, you should probably use insserv to manage your init scripts.  Add a header to the script like so:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:       capslock-remap
# Required-Start: $all
# Required-Stop:  
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:   
# Description:    Remap CapsLock to Escape
### END INIT INFO
```

And then run insserv:

```
insserv capslock
```

Comment: You must have posted right after I replied to my own question. In the spirit of points, you can have the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I hit the post button and your answer showed up as "one minute ago"!  Thanks for the points.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I used the command `insserv capslock` and everything started working.

Also, I needed to add an LSB header:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          capslock
# Required-Start:    
# Required-Stop:     
# Default-Start:     1 2 3 4 5 6
# Default-Stop:      
# Short-Description: 
# Description:       Remaps Caps Lock key to Escape
### END INIT INFO
setkeycodes 0x3a 1
```